# pip install --editable says "Successfully installed" but does not show in pip list

Tags: python, pip

`pip install --editable /path-to-code` in some linux environments does not work (says "Successfully installed", but then does not show in `pip list`).

`pip install /path-to-code` works as normal.

What do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install --editable` in such environments creates a `.egg-link` file in `site-packages` folder, but `pip list` looks at `dist-packages` folder

The fix is then to remove the `site-packages` folder and soft-link it to the `dist-packages` folder

In my machine this was:

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ ;
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

and then

```
pip install --editable /path-to-code
```